# How to set a property value from an expression tree?

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

I would like to set the property value referenced in an expression tree.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp8
{
    class TestObject
    {
        public double X { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static Action<double> GetSetterForX(Expression<Func<double>> expression)
        {
            var body = expression.Body;
            var operand = body as MemberExpression;
            var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo) (operand.Member);
            var setter = propertyInfo.GetSetMethod(true);

            // At this point I have the setter. But how do I get access to the testObject?

            return null;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testObject = new TestObject();
            var setter = GetSetterForX(() => testObject.X);
            setter.Invoke(5);
            Debug.Assert(testObject.X == 5);
        }
    }
}
```

I can get the setter but can not find a way to get access to the instance (testObject). Is there a way?

Note that this is a simplified example. I will use much more complex expressions with many property references inside and I would like to be able to set all of them (individually).

UPDATE

To clarify. I would like to have a setter returned which only takes a double and it assigns testObject's X property. This should be possible without the need to explicitly pass in the reference to testObject in the setter.
I can do the same to get a getter but not for setter. Here is the getter code:

```
static Func<double> GetGetterForX(Expression<Func<double>> expression)
{
    var body = expression.Body;
    var operand = body as MemberExpression;
    var result = new Func<double>(() => (double) GetValue(operand));

    return result;
}

private static object GetValue(MemberExpression member)
{
    var objectMember = Expression.Convert(member, typeof(object));
    var getterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(objectMember);
    var getter = getterLambda.Compile();
    return getter();
}
```

The getter returned is always working on the testObject instance. No need to pass in the testObject again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As soon as the input lambda expression represents member accessor, you can use [Expression.Assign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.assign?view=netframework-4.8) passing the input lambda expression body and parameter representing the value, e.g.

```
static Action<double> GetSetterForX(Expression<Func<double>> expression)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "value");
    var body = Expression.Assign(expression.Body, parameter);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<double>>(body, parameter);
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return `MethodInfo` instead of `Action<double>`, also the `Invoke(object obj, object[] params)` takes the original object and the parameters :

```cs
static MethodInfo GetSetterForX(Expression<Func<double>> expression)
{
    var body = expression.Body;
    var operand = body as MemberExpression;
    var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)(operand.Member);
    var setter = propertyInfo.GetSetMethod(true);
    return setter;
}

public static void Main()
{
    var testObject = new TestObject();
    var setter = GetSetterForX(() => testObject.X);
    setter.Invoke(testObject, new object[]{5});
    Debug.Assert(testObject.X == 5);
}
```

Fiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/CHJGbk

Comment: This is not what I want. I want to be able to get the value of X from testobject just by providing the `() => testObject.X` expression. I believe that this should be possible, I can write a GetGetter. I will update the question